# Free Fermion and Dirac Delta

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, fermions, dirac-delta-distributions

Taking [this paper (Zinn-Justin: Six-Vertex, Loop and Tiling Modles: Integrability and combinatorics)](http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~pzinn/publi/hdr.pdf) as reference (chapter 1), I would like to ask a question. First of all some fixed points:

1. The usual quantization condition (in a siutable signature): 
   $$\{ψ(z),ψ(w)\} = δ(z-w);\tag{1}$$
2. As (1.1), flippin a sign:
   $$
   ψ(z)=∑_{k∈\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}}ψ_kz^{-k-\frac{1}{2}},
   \qquad\qquad\qquad
   ψ^*(w)=∑_{k∈\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}}ψ^*_kw^{k-\frac{1}{2}};\tag{2}
   $$
3. Then the anticommutation relation:
   $$
   \{ψ_r,ψ^*_s \}= δ_{r,s}.\tag{3}
   $$

### PROBLEM

I would like to get $(1)$ using $(2)$ and $(3)$ but

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\{ψ(z),ψ^*(w)\} &= ∑_{r∈\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}}∑_{s∈\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}}z^{-k-\frac{1}{2}}w^{k-\frac{1}{2}}\{ψ_r,ψ^*_s\}\\
&= ∑_{r∈\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1}{2}}z^{-r-\frac{1}{2}}w^{r-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= w^{-1}∑_{n∈\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

in this last passage I set $r+\frac{1}{2}=n$. Now the problem is to evaluate that series. Of course if, naively

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
∑_{n∈\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n 
&= ∑_{n=0}^∞ \left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n + ∑_{n=0}^{∞}\left(\frac{z}{w} \right) -1\\
&= \frac{1}{1-\frac{w}{z}} + \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{w}} -1\\
&= 0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

this apparent paradox, I think, is because of the radius of convergence of the series: the first converge if $|w|<|z|$, while the second if $|z|<|w|$.

### QUESTION

How can I solve this paradox and get (with some $δ$-representation and analytic continuation) the result $(1)$?

Comment: You are done, taking into account the singularity of the series for $w=z$.

Comment: How can I take into account it? Where does the delta come from? Then there is that $w^{-1}$ over all...

Comment: You have just proven that the series is zero when $w\ne z$. Just note that when $w=z$ is infinity and this is nothing else than the definition of the Dirac's delta.

Comment: First of all the series *never* converges. Then the definition of delta is not just a function that is $∞$ when its argument is zero. Then when $z=w$ I get $w^{-1}∑_{n}1$, which regularization do you mean?

Comment: I assume $\sum_n 1=\infty$ taking for granted your evaluation for $w\ne z$. Anyway, the best approach to check if the behavior is that of a delta is by a test function and integration.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Done in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lat us consider the series
$$
  \Sigma(z,w)=w^{-1}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^n
$$
and take a test function $f(z)$. One has
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Sigma(z,w)f(z)dz=
w^{-1}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}w^n\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(z)}{z^n}dz.
$$
Moving to the complex domain and choosing a proper path, we recognize here the coefficients of a Laurent series and, indeed, our integral is just proportional to $f(w)$. So, we can identify $\Sigma(z,w)$ with $\delta(z-w)$, neglecting a possible multiplication constant.

Comment: Is that $w^{-1}$ that worries me!

Comment: No, indeed, as the coefficients of the  Laurent series are given  with $z^{-n-1}$. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series.

Comment: Yeah, of course since I have to pick the residue I need an extra power, you're right. I'm still a bit perplex about the question of convergence

Comment: Indeed, about convergence I have been somewhat cavalier but consider that I am working with distributions and that $f(z)$  must belong to a set of well-behaved test functions.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about the contour: maybe there is a pole at infinity...